# Groupby and replacing certain values with a random number in a certain range for each group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, pandas-groupby

The question is about updating the values of a column with unique values for each group in groupby based on some conditions.

I have a dataframe like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': ['m1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3'],
                   'name':['peter', 'mike', 'jeff', 'john', 'alex', 'joe', 'jeff', 'peter', 'alex', 'li', 'joe', 'tom', 'mike', 'john', 'tom', 'peter'],
                   'rank': [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
                  'rating': [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1550, 1540, 1640, 1500, 1390, 1500, 1450, 1500, 1720, 1500, 1320, 1500]})
```

I need to modify some numbers for each group of values in "match_id" based on a condition about another column.

So, I did a groupby on match_id first. Now, for every 1500 in the column "rating", I want to update the corresponding values in column "rank" with a value within the range of 1 to the length of the corresponding group which is also unqiue in the group.

This is what I've done so far:

```py
new = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = df.groupby('match_id', sort=False)
for name, dfg in grouped:
    dfm = dfg.copy()
    num = len(dfm.loc[dfm['rating'] == 1500])
    dfm.loc[dfm['rating'] == 1500, 'rank'] = np.random.choice(range(1,len(dfm)+1), num, replace=False)
    new = pd.concat([new, dfm], sort = True)
```

This works but has two problems. First, numbers generated this way may already exist within the group (on other rows). I want the generated random numbers to be unique, meaning the numbers do not already exist within the corresponding group.

Second, this takes way too long for my original dataset (125000 groups). So I need it to be also much more efficient and faster than loc.

This is what I expect to get as the output (note the "rank" column)

```py
    match_id    name    rank    rating
0         m1    peter      6    1500
1         m1    mike       5    1500
2         m1    jeff       4    1500
3         m1    john       3    1500
4         m1    alex       1    1550
5         m1    joe        2    1540
6         m2    jeff       1    1640
7         m2    peter      2    1500
8         m2    alex       4    1390
9         m2    li         5    1500
10        m2    joe        3    1450
11        m2    tom        6    1500
12        m3    mike       1    1720
13        m3    john       4    1500
14        m3    tom        3    1320
15        m3    peter      2    1500
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that `num=len(dfm['rating'] == 1500)` is the same as `num=len(dfm)`, right?

Comment: Of course, I forgot to put .loc. Edited

Comment: @QuangHoang Also made some changes to avoid errors

Comment: You should probably provide some expected output for the sample data as well. It's pretty unclear from your problem statement what you're looking to do.

Comment: @Randy Added the expected output. (Note: numbers were randomly generated for column "rank"). The point is that the generated numbers should not be repetitive within each group (considering all numbers in that group and not just the generated numbers).

Comment: You probably just want `df.groupby('match_id').rating.rank(method='first', ascending=False)`.

Comment: Great! that works. Thanks